# isplaying data of an existing database in Django admin site

Tags: python, database, django

I'm struggling with displaying data of an existing database in Django admin site. I created a model reflecting the table in an existing database, register in admin.py, run the makemigrations and migrate. the table created in models appears in admi site but not data from the database. english is my second language sorry for the typos.

Comment: I solve this problem by following this doc https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/legacy-databases/

Comment: https://books.agiliq.com/projects/django-orm-cookbook/en/latest/existing_database.html